# Raspberry pi 3B+ vs Raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, pi-4

what are pro and cons of Raspberry pi 3B+ vs Raspberry pi 4 ? For a new beginner like me which one to start with either Raspberry pi 3B+ or Raspberry pi 4 ?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Just buy the Pi4 2GB or Pi4 4GB. Its much faster only downside it does run hotter.

Comment: Pi4 is newer, faster, and equipped with better ethernet, bluetooth, usb, and power management, as well as options for larger amounts of RAM instead of the Pi3B+'s 1 GB.

Comment: An important difference is that the Pi4 **cannot boot from an external SSD,** while the Pi3b+ can (a external SSD connected via USB) even without any SD Card.

Comment: There is a saying the more the marrier. Now you decide what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro and cons of Raspberry pi 3B+ vs Raspberry pi 4 depends on what you want to do. You don't specify it. So for a beginner to just start learning with Raspberry Pi I suggest to use a Raspberry Pi 4B. It is the latest version and has important improvements about Raspberry Pi 3B+, mainly real 1GB ethernet, USB 3.0, larger amounts of RAM up to 4 GByte, boot loader in a reprogrammable EEPROM and other things. At this time the RPi 4B cannot boot from another device than the SD Card, like USB SSD or net boot from ethernet but that will come soon. They are working on it and with reprogramming the EEPROM they will upgrade the RPi 4B with this functions.

For further information you are encouraged to compare
[specification for RPi 3B+](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-3bplus-specs-benchmarks) and
[specification for RPi 4B](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks).